# the import xxxx cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse

A ver si alguien sabe como solucionar esto porque estoy ligeramente desesperado.

He creado un proyecto con Eclipse 2018-09. Utilizo java-11-openjdk-amd64 como versión de java y trabajo sobre un Ubuntu 18-04.

He empezado el proyecto creando una clase una conexión a una base de datos mysql utilizando mysql-connector-java-8.0.13.jar y ejecutando una inserción en la BD sin ningún problema. En esta clase realizo un import de java.sql.*. Hasta aquí todo bien.

El caso es que he creado una clase dentro del proyecto que hace uso de un jar externo, que voy a llamar imprescindible.jar. He procedido **exactamente igual** que con el jar del mysql. Es decir:

1. He pegado el fichero imprescindible.jar dentro de un directorio  que he llamado librerias dentro de mi proyecto.
2. Lo he incorporado al classpath del proyecto, por lo que imprescindible.jar ha aparecido en las References Libraries del proyecto.
3. Al utilizar la clase que está dentro de imprescindible.jar en mi clase, me aparece subrayada en rojo, ya que todavía no lo he importado. Hasta aquí todo correcto.
4. Colocando el ratón encima de la llamada a esa clase, Eclipse me propone varias soluciones, entre ellas la de añadir la importación de la clase que proporciona imprescindible.jar. Todo bien. Es algo que he hecho mil veces.
5. Selecciono la importación de dicha clase y aquí empiezan los problemas.

El import com.imprescindible.* me aparece subrayado en rojo. Poniendo el ratón encima me dice "the import com.imprescindible cannot be resolved".

¿Cómo puede decir eso si el mismo eclipse me lo ha sugerido como solución?
¿Porque funciona sin problemas con el connector de mysql y no con esta librería?
La clase que necesito esta en la librería en cuestión, me he asegurado de ello.
En internet sólo encuentro la solución de añadir el jar al classpath, pero ese creo que no es mi problema.

Un saludo y gracias anticipadas.

Comment: En las `Referenced Libraries`, puedes expandir el jar para ver las clases que incluye. Comprueba que estén las clases que necesitas.

Comment: Eso he hecho y allí está. Así es como me he asegurado de que estaba la clase que necesito.

Comment: Pues estoy de acuerdo que debería funcionar... con la descripción que haces ya solo se me ocurriría revisar errores "tontos" (¿es el nombre del package exactamente el que has escrito?¿has añadido el jar al proyecto correcto y no al que está justo encima?) y lo que ya serían fallos del Eclipse (volver a crear proyecto a ver si vuelve a pasar, crear una clase mínima que use el package y ver si se puede compilar por línea de comandos,...)

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, aunque me quedo con las ganas de saber porqué. Creé otro proyecto y me pasaba lo mismo. Lo que he hecho ha sido utilizar la anterior versión de Eclipse, Oxigen, y me ha funcionado a la primera.